# Approximate sin() to {1, 0, -1} gives wrong results

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, rounding-error

I am trying to make a function that is an approximation to sin() so that it takes the values 1, 0 or -1. This code

```
var periodicity = 2 * Math.PI;   
var sin3 = function(t) {
  var tmod = (t / periodicity) % 1;
  if (tmod < 1/8)
    return 0
  else if (tmod < 3/8)
    return Math.sign(tmod)
  else if (tmod < 5/8)
    return 0
  else if (tmod < 7/8)
    return -Math.sign(tmod)
  else return 0;
}
```

has the problem that when a variable is an integer/8 it sometimes gets an inconsistent value. For example the code

```
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  sin3(i/8*2*Math.PI)
}
```

gets the values

[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, **1**, 0, -1, -1, **-1**, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0]

The 12th element should be 0 but becomes 1.
The 16th element should be 0 but becomes -1.

Changing periodicity to 1 did not help. Working with increments 2^-n should be precise on a binary architecture, I thought.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ephyckf1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, `i/8` has an exact binary representation.
Therefore `(i/8) * ((2*Math.PI) / (2*Math.PI))` will not suffer from floating point rounding error, but `(i/8*2*Math.PI) / (2*Math.PI)` *will*. This is due to the fact that the intermediate result `(i/8*2*Math.PI)` has no exact floating point representation.

Having said that, why do you bother? For every odd value of `i` (which includes the 12th and 16th element), you are *precisely* on the boundary between two different approximations, so it is arbitrary whichever is returned.